# how to restrict read permisson to some directories,while somes are with no read permission in gitolite?

Tags: git, permissions, directory, gitolite

git version is 1.7.0.4.
My repository tree is like below,

```
reponame
--------code
------------sevenEleven
------------out
```

I need to limit `sevenEleven` read permission only to `mary`, and `out` read permission only to `jack`.
I tried following setting, but failed.
For `mary`, she can read both code and `sevenEleven` directory.

```
R                 =  mary
R  NAME/code/out/ =mary
```

Does anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitolite cannot restrict "read" access for a part of the repo, only write access.

Read access are for a all repo, for clone or fetch operations.

See "[applying deny rules during the first check](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html#deny-rules)"

The [VREF `NAME`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME) is only there to prevent write (modification or push) for files and directory, not read access.

A true read access would be by having `sevenEleven` and `out` in their own git repos.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert those directories to sub-modules so they can be managed independently.

However it probably won't be easy because of the many different ways folk use, abuse and make mistakes with sub-modules.

Originally they were a way of including a static or slow moving library at a specific revision. It can get hard when they are dynamic entities. Maybe re-think what it is about those directories that needs those permissions and find an alternative mechanism for the data transfer.